# Get last element of QStringList

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QString` List like this

```
daily-logs.06-01-2015.01 
daily-logs.06-01-2015.02 
daily-logs.06-01-2015.03
```

Now I would like to get new `QStringList` get the number last of the string like this

`01 
02 
03`:

```
QStringList list = folder_file.entryList(nameFilter);

for(int i=0;i<list.count();i++){
    qDebug()<<list.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData();


    QStringList list2=list.at(i).split(".");
    for(int j=0;j<list2.count();j++){
        //qDebug()<<list2.at(j).toLocal8Bit().constData();
        QString list3=list2.value(list2.length()-1);

        qDebug()<<list3;
        //qDebug()<<list3;
    }
```

I am able to get only the last value. But I think this is more for loop. So does anyone have a method to get this more performance.

Answer (score 6):

Use special file `QFileInfo::suffix` function:

```
const auto& list = folder_file.entryList(nameFilter);
QStringList output;   
for(const auto& f : list)   
    output << QFileInfo(f).suffix();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is too dirty...

```
QStringList DoSomeDirtyWork( const QStringList& input )
{
  QStringList output;

  for ( auto it = input.constBegin(); it != input.constEnd(); ++it )
  {
    const QString& src = *it;
    const int pos = src.lastIndexOf('.');
    output << src.mid( pos );
  }

  return output;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.Im try but i still get Error

invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
initializing argument 1 of ‘QString::QString(const char*)’

Comment: `char` is a simple type. `const char *` is a **pointer** to a constant **array** of chars. Of course it is not convertable.

Answer (score 2):

```
QStringList list = folder_file.entryList(nameFilter);
for (int i = 0; i < list.count(); ++i) {
    QStringList wordList = list[i].split('.');
    qDebug() << wordList.takeLast();
}
```

Maybe it is not so cute and short as it could be but it is an example without QFileInfo.